# Want to make it so prices actually reflect the choices

Tags: javascript

Hope everyone is having a good weekend!

If you select a Small Cheese pizza the price comes out to $5. However, if you select a Small Cheese and Peanut Butter, it still comes out to $5. I think I might need to add a loop/array. I am definitely missing something. Thanks for your help. Also, I am a total newbie to all of this so no answers that are may seem out of knowledge based off what I have written. Thanks!

```js
var pizzaPrice = 0;

function Pizza(size,toppings,pizzaPrice) {
  this.size = size;
  this.toppings = toppings;
  this.pizzaPrice = 0;
}

Pizza.prototype.price = function() {
  if (this.size === "Small") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 2;
  }
  else if (this.size === "Medium") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 3;
  }
  else if (this.size === "Large") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 4;
  }
  if (this.toppings === "Cheese") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 3;
  }

  else if (this.toppings === "Cheese" && this.toppings === "Peanut Butter") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 10;
    console.log("hey");

  }

  else if (this.toppings === "Vegetarian") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 2;
  }
  else if (this.toppings === "Supreme") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 4;
  }
  else if (this.toppings === "Pepperoni") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 3;
  }

return this.pizzaPrice;
}






$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#pizza").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var size = $("input[type=radio][name=size]:checked").val();
    var toppings = $("input[type=checkbox][name=toppings]:checked").val();
    var newPizza = new Pizza(size,toppings,pizzaPrice);
    newPizza.price();

    $("#responses").append("<li>" + "You ordered a " + newPizza.size + " " + newPizza.toppings + " pizza. " + " Your total price is " + newPizza.pizzaPrice + "</li>");


      });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pizza Pizza</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Pizza Toppings</h2>
      </div>
      <form id="pizza">
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>What size would you like your pizza:</p>
          <input type="radio" name="size" value="Small">Small.<br>
          <input type="radio" name="size" value="Medium">Medium.<br>
          <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large">Large.<br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>Which toppings would you like</p>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Cheese">Cheese.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Supreme">Supreme.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Fruit">Fruit.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Bacon">Bacon.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Artichoke">Artichoke.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Peanut Butter">Peanut butter.<br>
        </div>
       <button type="submit">Let's get your order</button>
      </form>
      <ul id="responses">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot be using `else if` in case of toppings if you want to add them up. The size being single select is fine though with `else if` as only one will be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to get values of all checked toppings in an array, currently you are getting only the first one. Then you need to add prices for each topping selected while calculating the price. you can use `indexOf` for this:

```js
var pizzaPrice = 0;

function Pizza(size,toppings,pizzaPrice) {
  this.size = size;
  this.toppings = toppings;
  this.pizzaPrice = 0;
}

Pizza.prototype.price = function() {
  if (this.size === "Small") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 2;
  }
  else if (this.size === "Medium") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 3;
  }
  else if (this.size === "Large") {
    this.pizzaPrice += 4;
  }
  if (this.toppings.indexOf("Cheese") >= 0) {
    this.pizzaPrice += 3;
  }

  if (this.toppings.indexOf("Peanut Butter") >= 0) {
    this.pizzaPrice += 10;

  }

  if (this.toppings.indexOf("Vegetarian") >= 0) {
    this.pizzaPrice += 2;
  }
  if (this.toppings.indexOf("Supreme") >= 0) {
    this.pizzaPrice += 4;
  }
  if (this.toppings.indexOf("Pepperoni") >= 0) {
    this.pizzaPrice += 3;
  }

return this.pizzaPrice;
}






$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#pizza").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var size = $("input[type=radio][name=size]:checked").val();
    var toppings = [];
    $("input[type=checkbox][name=toppings]:checked").each(function(){
           toppings.push($(this).val());
    });
    var newPizza = new Pizza(size,toppings,pizzaPrice);
    newPizza.price();

    $("#responses").append("<li>" + "You ordered a " + newPizza.size + " " + newPizza.toppings + " pizza. " + " Your total price is " + newPizza.pizzaPrice + "</li>");


      });
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pizza Pizza</title>
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Pizza Toppings</h2>
      </div>
      <form id="pizza">
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>What size would you like your pizza:</p>
          <input type="radio" name="size" value="Small">Small.<br>
          <input type="radio" name="size" value="Medium">Medium.<br>
          <input type="radio" name="size" value="Large">Large.<br>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <p>Which toppings would you like</p>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Cheese">Cheese.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Vegetarian">Vegetarian.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Supreme">Supreme.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Fruit">Fruit.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Bacon">Bacon.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Artichoke">Artichoke.<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="toppings" value="Peanut Butter">Peanut butter.<br>
        </div>
       <button type="submit">Let's get your order</button>
      </form>
      <ul id="responses">
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement here

```
var toppings = $("input[type=checkbox][name=toppings]:checked").val();
```

is incorrect. As it is returning you the value of first checked `checkbox`.
Instead use following statement to get an array of checked values.

```
var toppings = $("input[type=checkbox][name=toppings]:checked").get();
```

Now while retrieving the values you can use the following:

```
(this.toppings.indexOf("Cheese") >= 0)
```

The `indexOf()` returns `-1` if no matching results is found. 
Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues -

1.) When you do

```
var toppings = $("input[type=checkbox][name=toppings]:checked").val();
```

you already lost all the toppings except the first one. Instead you could use

```
var toppings = $("input[type=checkbox][name=toppings]:checked");
    var i = 0;
    var toppingVal;
    while(i < toppings.length){
        toppingVal += " "+(toppings[i]).value;
      i++;
    }
```

2.) When you are calculating the price, you make use of `if..else..if` blocks. How can you add up multiple toppings, only one block would execute. use only `if`

3.) As per my suggestion you would get a string of toppings seperated by a space(`' '`). So you cannot be using `===` for comparison. Use `indexOf` to find if the toppings string contains a specific topping.

Take a look at this fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/8u67x4nm/1/ . Works fine.